# How to navigate through scenes?

Tags: javafx, multi-window

I have created some scenes using sceneBuilder and now i need to link those scenes.for example when the user click  the "next" button the next scene is displayed.
In android it is possible to go from one activity(window) to another easily(using Intent and startActivity Method).
Is there anything like that in javafx.
If it isn't .what is the best way to navigate through scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You navigate by replacing the children of your topmost container. In the simplest case, it is the primary stage. So:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    ...
    primaryStage.setRoot(view1);
    ...
}

public void navigateToView2() {
    primaryStage.setRoot(view1);
}
```

You may want to have a common template; in this case your topmost container will be the container of the template.